# unable to use git commands - operation not permitted

Tags: linux, git, github

when using git commands, I am getting below error

```
git fetch 
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

and on doing chmod I get,

```
sudo chmod 777 .git/FETCH_HEAD 
sudo: unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: setresuid() [0, 0, 0] -> [117, -1, -1]: Operation not permitted
```

please suggest what could be the matter?

Comment: Are you sure that you need chmod and not chown to resolve it? Do you use selinux?

Answer (score 0):

For use from 'sudo', your account must be in sudoer group. use 'usermod' for adding you to 'sudo' group. Or you can use from 'su' and run chown or chmod command with 'root'.